# Advance layout.xml in android

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

Can anyone please tell by using we can easily create a beautiful layout in android by just drag and drop.
I am know using android tool for building xml which is too much hectic task so kindly guide me

Comment: so you ask for a way to easily create a layout with drag n drop? android studio should be enough, there are a lot of parameters in every layout element so its difficult to do much without manually setting parameters

Comment: You cant, the better you can do is with ConstraintLayout and setting all layouts trough mouse, but still needes very understanding of the xml and constraints

Answer (score 0):

On your layout.xml file you can switch from 'Text' to 'Design' where you can drag and drop views but even after drag and drop you need to set parameters to define dimensions of the views where you should rely on xml.